# Use Ansible set_fact from ec2 results.

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, ansible

I've seen several examples but setting the IP from the results of launching ec2 intances are failing. anyone have an idea why ? 
Iam using ansible 2.0.1.0

The task to launch 3 instances in 3 different subnets works corectly as follows.

```
  tasks:
- name: elastic instance provisioning
  local_action:
    module: ec2
    region: "{{ region }}"
    key_name: "{{ key }}"
    instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
    image: "{{ image }}"
    user_data: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/ansible/host_vars/elasticsearch/user_data') }}"
    key_name: "{{ key }}"
    wait: yes
    count: 1
    group: ["{{ main_sg }}", "{{ jenkins_sg}}"]
    instance_tags:
       Name: elastic-test-cluster
       class: database
       environment: staging
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item }}"
    assign_public_ip: no
  with_items:
     - "{{ private_subnet_1 }}"
     - "{{ private_subnet_2 }}"
     - "{{ private_subnet_3 }}"
  register: ec2
- debug: msg="{{ ec2.results[0].instances[0].private_ip }}"
```

I can debug and get expected result

```
TASK [debug]    
ok: [localhost] => {
"msg": "10.1.100.190"
}
```

But this next part in the playbook fails.

```
- name: Add Ip for each Server
  set_fact:
    instance_private_ip0: "{{ ec2.results[0].instances[0].private_ip }}"
    instance_private_ip1: "{{ ec2.results[1].instances[1].private_ip }}"
    instance_private_ip2: "{{ ec2.results[2].instances[2].private_ip }}"
  register: result
- debug: var=result
```

The Results from the debug is the following. Not sure what to make of it.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "list object has no element 1"}
```

Comment: I guess it's only capturing the last item

Comment: Per iteration the module will probably only return one item, so the instance should always be accessed as `instances[0]`. `ec2.results[2].instances[0].private_ip`

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop over the results of the previous task:

```
- name: Add Ip for each Server
  set_fact:
    instance_private_ip{{ item.0 }}: "{{ item.1.instances[0].private_ip }}"
  with_indexed_items: "{{ ec2.results }}"
```

Don't be confused here about `item.0` and `item.1`. [The `with_indexed_items` loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-a-list-with-an-index) provides two items per iteration. `item.0` is the index (0, 1, 2, ...) and `item.1` is the actual content.

Comment: Thank You, I will give that a try, I think I see where I got confused. In the mean time iam using ansible to launch with a user_data file to run a bash commands on each server to configure the cluster. But will correct my mistakes and give it a go.